# Gitlab CI - Custom variable as a branch in trigger downstream

Tags: gitlab-ci

I would like to use a custom variable as branch inside a trigger downstream stage, but it looks like so far that `before_script` (when I put the variable assignment) is not called before a trigger stage.
That leads to not have the desired branch triggered, because of empty `$CUSTOM_VARIABLE`.

Basically, this is to trigger the child on a specific TAG name instead of the branch name, if TAG is given...

Here is a sample code showing what I want to do:

```
default:
  before_script:
      if [ $CONDITION ];
      then
         CUSTOM_VARIABLE=$TAG_NAME;
      else
         CUSTOM_VARIABLE=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME;
      fi

build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    VAR1: var1
    VAR2: var2
  trigger:
    project: my/child/project
    branch: $CUSTOM_VARIABLE
    strategy: depend
```

I also tried to assign the variable conditionally inside `variables`, but the code is not evaluated and is pasted as it is inside the custom variable.

```
variables:
  CUSTOM_VARIABLE: $([ $CONDITION ] && echo "$TAG_NAME" || echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME")
```

Is there a way to use a custom variable as a trigger branch ?

Comment: I am struggling with similar issues. I need to expand a variable for the trigger project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dotenv

```
before_script:
      if [ $CONDITION ];
      then
         CUSTOM_VARIABLE=$TAG_NAME;
         echo "CUSTOM_VARIABLE=$CUSTOM_VARIABLE" >> build.env
      else
         CUSTOM_VARIABLE=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME;
         echo "CUSTOM_VARIABLE=$CUSTOM_VARIABLE" >> build.env
      fi
artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
```